# NSRegularExpression not matching number sign (#)

Tags: ios, regex, swift, unicode, nsregularexpression

I'm working on a Guitar Chord transposer, and so from a given text file, I want to identify guitar chords.  e.g. G#, Ab, F#m, etc.

I'm almost there!  I have run into a few problems already due to the number sign (hash tag).

#

For example, you can't include the number sign in your regex pattern.  The NSRegularExpression will not initialize with this:

```
let fail:    String = "\\b[ABCDEFG](b|#)?\\b"
let success: String = "\\b[CDEFGAB](b|\\u0023)?\\b"
```

I had to specifically provide the unicode character.  I can live with that.

However, now that I have a NSRegularExpression object, it won't match these (sharps = number sign) when I have a line of text such as:

Am        Bb   G#     C     Dm      F   E

When it starts processing the G#, the sharp associated with that second capture group is not matched.  (i.e. the NSTextCheckingResult's second range has a location of NSNotFound)  Note, it works for Bb... it matches the 'b'

I'm wondering what I need to do here.  It would seem the documentation doesn't cover this case of '#' which IS in fact sometimes used in Regex patterns (I think related to comments or sth)

One thing that would be great would be to not have to look up the unicode identifier for a #, but just use it as a String "#" then convert that so it plays nicely with the pattern.  There exists the chance that \u0023 is in fact not the code associated with # ...

Comment: Isn't the number sign different than the sharp symbol?

Comment: Let me precise: you do not want to match `Eddd`? What about `F#7`? The root cause is clear, but the solution needs to be tailored to this specific kind of input. And try `"\\b[CDEFGAB][bm\\u0023]?(?!\\w)"`. Or `\\b[CDEFGAB][bm\\u0023]?+(?!\\w)`. Not sure what suits here best. Please check.

Comment: Please check my 2 solutions above and let know which one works best.

Comment: @SumnerEvans My code ultimately will support both, but I'm being user-oriented here.  Most people write 'b' for flat (there is a flat symbol just not on your keyboard!), and # (number sign) for sharp (there is also a sharp symbol)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Please don't over-think.  I've shortened my code for brevity.  I have another capture group that deals with chord structures, and that works just fine.  The question is about matching the # sign.  Right now, I'm just making this example concise.  Right now I care about the note.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Could you please try to explain your answer rather than just paste code, telling me what to do?  Your example suggests I would have a tone [ABCDEFG] followed by a flat, a minor, or a sharp.  Which is definitely not what I want to do.  I'm concerning myself with which NOTE, not which chord (yet).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So what is this ```+(?!\\w)``` supposed to do?

Comment: I do not tell what to use. I cannot tell you for sure until I understand what input goes in, what the exact requirements are and what you need to get in the end. Does `\\b[CDEFGAB](b|\\u0023)?(?!\\w)` work? Or does `\\b[CDEFGAB](b|\\u0023)?+(?!\\w)` work? I will post a full answer once I understand what works for you. (Please do not get me wrong: my answers are detailed, and I do not want to lose time explaining something no one is going to use).

Comment: I already wrote what input goes in.  But, for now, it's this:  ```A   Bb   G#```  It will not match G#, but it will match Bb

I will add the chords later (such as Gm, G#7, G#maj7, and so on... it's a long list)  Trying to figure out why the sharp won't match.

But just matching notes,   ```\\b[CDEFGAB](b|\\u0023)?(?!\\w)``` worked.

My question is, what does this ```(?!\\w)``` do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152180/discussion-between-horseshoe7-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2):

The `\b` [**word boundary**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is a context dependent construct. It matches in 4 contexts: 1) between start of string and a word char, 2) between a word char and end of string, 3) between word and a non-word and 4) a non-word and a word char.

Your regex is written in such a way that ultimately the regex engine sees a `\b` after `#` and that means a `#` will only match if there is a word char after it.

If you replace `\b` with `(?!\w)`, a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a word char immediately to the right of the current location, it will work.

So, you may use

```
\\b[CDEFGAB](b|\\u0023)?(?!\\w)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oZddML/1).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[CDEFGAB]` - a char from the set
- `(b|\\u0023)?` - an optional sequence of `b` or `#`
- `(?!\\w)` - a negative lookahead failing the match (and causing backtracking into the preceding pattern! To avoid that, add `+` after `?` to prevent backtracking into that pattern) if there is a word char immediately to the right of the current position.

Comment: That looks great.  I'm still pretty new to Regex.  So the last piece of the puzzle is, I could have a chord that is ```G#``` but I could also have one that is ```G#m7```

There are a lot of flavours of chords out there, for example, my currently failing regex pattern is: ```"\\b[CDEFGAB](\\u0023|b|♯|♭)?(7\\(\\[\\u0023\\]5,b9\\)|maj13\\[\\u0023\\]11|7\\(b5,b9\\)|7\\(\\[\\u0023\\]5,\\[\\u0023\\]9\\)|7\\(b5,\\[\\u0023\\]9\\)|sus2sus4|maj9\\[\\u0023\\]11|m6add9|maj7b5|maj7\\[\\u0023\\]5)?\\b"```  (I left a bunch out due to comment limitations, but you get the idea)

Comment: I should also point out, it matches ```Ab```, but not ```G#```  Given my syntax, how does that make sense?

Comment: I get some different results with different variations. Please do not use musical terms, they do not help. You have `Ab` and `G#` , and I see [the regex matches them](https://regex101.com/r/284AC6/1). Is it working in all the cases? I just replaced the `?\\b` with `?+(?!\\w)`. Just provide me a string and say what should match and what should not.

Comment: ```A  B  C#  Db  G#m  A#7``` would be a good start.  Please recognize that anything that comes after the # or b could be from a list of 50 chords, so I need to build my pattern parametrically.

Comment: Like [this](https://regex101.com/r/284AC6/2)? Sorry,  your question becomes too vague now.

Comment: Yes, that seems to have done it!  I'll just point out that it's more general form is:

```"\\b[ABCDEFG](#|b)?+(.....)?+(?!\\w)"```  where .... is a capture group of chord constants, for example:

```sus2sus4|maj7|7|m``` which should be an exhaustive list of all the different types of chords.

Note, in all cases, one should convert the number sign to unicode, so no # but \\u0023 and because you can also have those in a chord name, such as ```maj7#5``` you would have to convert it to ```maj7[\\u0023]5```

I will upvote your answer but also repackage your answer for completeness.

Comment: Hahah now to extend the regex to identify a bass note:

```C#m7/G#```

It may have a slash after the guitar chord, followed by a note.

Expert level: Wiktor!

Comment: Ok, suit yourself. I actually explained the `?+` part in *and causing backtracking into the preceding pattern! To avoid that, add `+` after `?` to prevent backtracking into that pattern*. I can add more on that if you think it is the key.

Comment: To match optional substrings after a pattern, enclose that pattern with an optional non-capturing group. `A(?:/B)?` will match `A` and `A/B`.

Comment: I see I can edit your answer, so I'll append it in a way that really completes the answer in a way that one doesn't have to read through all these comments.  You've been a tremendous help, thank you!!!

Comment: Again, examples of input would be ```C#/G# C#m7/G#``` About music.  A note has a tone from A-G and could be sharp, flat, or nothing.  i.e ```A, Bb, C#, G```, etc.  A chord has a "flavour" attached to the note.  ```C#maj7``` and then that Chord can have a separate bass note, but doesn't need to.  E.g.  ```C#maj7/G#``` is this enough information to go on?  I am really having trouble with Regex in general and it seems worse on iOS.  I tried implementing your abstract form and NSRegularExpression threw an error

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: It is really necessary to write  the # character as `\u0023` in a regex pattern? `#` seems to work as well.

Comment: @MartinR  Did you try this in iOS?  Because creating a regexPattern without providing unicode results in NSRegularExpression(...) throwing an error.

Comment: @MartinR: I amjust trying to help OP understand how the existing pattern can be extended and why it did not work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I could really use your help for the last part of the problem.  Your help will be pretty useful for a lot of music-minded developers!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew ok, your abstract form provided a few comments ago works on regex101.com, so I guess I'll have to figure out the problem with NSRegularExpression.  There is hope... :)

Comment: @horseshoe7: Why does it throw any error? Please post the code you are trying. You usually get exceptions when the number of parentheses is not balanced (some `(` is not closed in most cases, but it can be vice versa.) A note on regex building: `A`, `A#`, `G#maj7`  can be defined with a pattern assigned to a variable. Then, you can create a "larger" pattern. So, if `let note = "[A-H](...|...|...)?+(?:...|...)?+(?!\\w)"` then you may say `let note_with_bass = note + "(?:/" + note + ")?"` to match an optional `/` + `note` after a `note`.

Comment: where should I post the code?  The comments section here is not really geared for that.  I am already doing what you suggest.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew this is currently my code:  https://gist.github.com/horseshoe7/eca9c9ba347607d025486acf9116d3e9

you could probably start at the method .parseChords(...) and follow the code from there.

Answer (score 0):

*(I'd like to first say @WiktorStribiżew has been a tremendous help and what I am writing now would not have been possible without him!  I'm not concerned about StackOverflow points and rep, so if you like this answer, please upvote his answer.)*

This issue took many turns and had a few issues going on.  *Ultimately this question should be called* **How do I use Regex on iOS to detect Musical Chords in a text file?**

The answer is (so far), not simply.

**CRASH COURSE IN MUSIC THEORY**

In music you have **notes**.  They are made up of a letter between `A->G` and an optional symbol called an **accidental**.  (A note relates to the acoustic frequency of the sound you hear when that note is played) An accidental can be a **flat** (represented as a `♭` or simply a `b`), or a **sharp** (represented as a `♯` or simply a `#`, as these are easier to type on a keyboard).  An accidental serves to make a note a semitone higher (#) or lower (b).  As such, a F# is the same acoustic frequency as a Gb.  On a piano, the white keys are notes with no accidentals, and the black keys represent notes with an accidental.  Depending on some factors of the piece of music, that piece won't mix accidental types.  It will either be flats throughout the piece or sharps. (Depending on the musical key of the composition, but this is not that relevant here.)

In terms of regex, you have something like  ABCDEFG? to determine the note.  In reality it's more complicated.

Then, a Musical **Chord** is comprised of the root note and it's *chord type*.  There are over 50 types of chords.  They have a 'text signature' that is unique.  Also, a 'major' chord has an empty signature.  So in terms of pseudo-regex you have for a Chord:

`[ABCDEFG](b|#)?(...|...|...)?`

where the first part you recognize as the note (as before), and the last optional is to determine the chord type.  The different types were omitted, but can be as simple as a `m` (for Minor chord), or `maj7#5` (for a major 7th chord with an augmented 5th... don't worry about it.  Just know there are many string constants to represent a chord type)

Then finally, with guitar you often have a corresponding **bass note** that changes the chord's tonality somewhat.  You denote this by adding a slash and then the note, giving the general pseudoform:

`[ABCDEFG](b|#)?(...|...|...)?(/[ABCDEFG](b|#)?)?  // NOT real Regex

real examples: C/F   or C#m/G#   and so on`

where the last part has a slash then the same pattern to recognize a note.

So putting these all together, in general we want to find chords that could take on many forms, such as:

`F   Gm   C#maj7/G#  F/C  Am  A7  A7/F#  Bmaj13#11`

I was hoping to find one Regex to rule them all.  I ended up writing code that works, though it seems like I kind of hacked around a bit to get the results I desired.

You can [see this code here](https://gist.github.com/horseshoe7/4ca734e7e9153aa3684e8f6429221add), written in Swift.  It is not complete for my purposes, but it will parse a string, return a list of Chord Results and their text range within the original string.  From there you would have to finish the implementation to suit your needs.

There have been a few issues on iOS:

- iOS does not handle the number sign (#) well at all.  When providing regex patterns or match text, I either had to replace the # with its unicode \u0023, or what ultimately worked was replacing all occurrences of # with another character (such as 'S'), and then convert it back once regex did it's thing.  So this code I wrote often has to 'sanitize' the pattern or the input text before doing anything.
- I couldn't get a Regex Pattern to perfectly parse a chord structure.  It wasn't fully working for a Chord with a bass note, but it would successfully match a Chord with a bass note, then I had to split those 2 components and parse them separately, then recombine them
- Regex is really a bit of voodoo, and I think it sucks that for something so confusing to many people, there are also different platform-dependent implementations of it.  For example, Wiktor referred me to Regex patterns he wrote to help me solve the problem on www.regex101.com, that would WORK on that website, but these would not work on iOS, and NSRegularExpression would throw an error (often it had something to do with this # character)
- My solution pays absolutely no regard to performance.  It just wanted it to work.